# How to plot two 3D plots of matrices on the same figure with same scale in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot

I have two matrices and I would like to have their corresponding two 3D plots on two subplots on the same figure, with the same z axis.

This is my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D

def myplot(matrix1, matrix2):
    mymin = np.min(np.array([np.min(matrix1), np.min(matrix2)]))
    mymax = np.max(np.array([np.max(matrix1), np.max(matrix2)]))

    xsize, ysize = matrix1.shape
    x = np.arange(0, ysize, 1)
    y = np.arange(0, xsize, 1)

    xs, ys = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    z1 = matrix1
    z2 = matrix2

    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
    ax1 = Axes3D(fig)
    ax1.plot_surface(xs, ys, z1, rstride=1, cstride=1)
    ax2 = Axes3D(fig)
    ax2.plot_surface(xs, ys, z2, rstride=1, cstride=1)
    plt.tight_layout
    plt.show()

mat1 = np.random.random(size = (10, 10))
mat2 = np.random.random(size = (10, 10))

myplot(mat1, mat2)
```

- Why do I only see one 3D plot?
- How can I have the same z axis in both plots?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to generate the sub plots

See plot below (I've changed the colouring too)

```
def myplot(matrix1, matrix2):
    mymin = np.min(np.array([np.min(matrix1), np.min(matrix2)]))
    mymax = np.max(np.array([np.max(matrix1), np.max(matrix2)]))

    xsize, ysize = matrix1.shape
    x = np.arange(0, ysize, 1)
    y = np.arange(0, xsize, 1)

    xs, ys = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    z1 = matrix1
    z2 = matrix2
    fig=plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1, projection='3d')
    ax1.plot_surface(xs, ys, z1,color="blue",alpha=0.5,rstride=1, cstride=1)
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2, projection='3d')
    ax2.plot_surface(xs, ys, z2,color="green",alpha=0.5, rstride=1, cstride=1)
    plt.tight_layout
    plt.show()

mat1 = np.random.random(size = (10, 10))
mat2 = np.random.random(size = (10, 10))

myplot(mat1, mat2)
```

[image]

**Edit:**
To impose `mymin` and `mymax` as limits of the two z axes, use

```
ax1.set_zlim(mymin, mymax)
ax2.set_zlim(mymin, mymax)
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant two subplots, each with one of the two matrices.